# add user details from my asp.net application to windows server database

Tags: asp.net, windows-server-2008-r2

I have developed an ASP.NET application on Visual studio 2010, which takes user details( user name,password etc).
I want to add these user details to the database on Windows Server 2008 R2 which is already created. Can you please tell me the steps how to do this or even some code as I am new to this?

Comment: You could do with clarifying your question slightly.  What kind of database?  What have you done so far.  Have you looked at the built in ASP.net membership stuff http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asp.net 2 and up with Membership Framework(choose webproject template) makes life easier for caputuring user registration etc. with minimilistic coding.

Refer this step by step tutorial (for sqlserver)
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/creating-the-membership-schema-in-sql-server-cs

**Switch(target database)**

- case "Sql Server": use SqlMembershipProvider Refer: 
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa478949.aspx or as above
- case "Oracle": use OracleMembershipProvider Refer:
  http://docs.oracle.com/html/E10928_01/OracleMembershipProviderClass.htm
- case "MySql": Use MySqlMembershipProvider Refer:
  http://www.integratedwebsystems.com/2010/02/how-to-setup-and-configure-mysql-membership-provider-6-2-2-porting-to-mono-part-2-of-3/
- case Other:

  - Google for any existing providers
  - Create your own provider (not a big deal). Refer: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx
  - Update your question with more information

Hope this helps and good luck

Krishna